# Display changes in map layer while editing attribute table in qgis

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table, editing

I am new to qgis.

I would like to see changes on the map in real time while I am editing the associated attribute file.  Currently, I have the poly id field labels turned on.  I cannot see the changes to the poly id on the map unless I refresh the screen.  It would be really helpful to see the changes on the map as I enter them in the attribute table.

Answer (score 3):

Updating the map view whenever an attribute value is changed in the attribute table could impact the performance in a very negative way.

A workaround - if you want to see changes immediately - could be to edit not in the attribute table but in the feature attribute form which opens when you click on a feature with the Identify tool ("auto open form" needs to be checked).